# View release for user on multiple devices

Tags: fabric.io

Is it possible to see what release a particular user is running on their device(s).

For example user joesmith@myapp.com is running my app. He claims to be running version 2 but the behavior in the app makes me think that he is running version 1.1.

Is there a way to look up that user in fabric.io (assuming that we are calling setUserIdentifier) and seeing ALL the versions that user is running?